# how vscode active provideInlineCompletionItems by user explicitly triggers

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode api, we can use provideInlineCompletionItems to implemetn inline completions whenever the user stopped typing. but how can i implement user explicitly triggers?

```
export interface InlineCompletionItemProvider {

      /**
       * Provides inline completion items for the given position and document.
       * **If inline completions are enabled, this method will be called whenever the user stopped typing.**
       * **It will also be called when the user explicitly triggers inline completions **or explicitly asks for the next or previous inline completion.
       * In that case, all available inline completions should be returned.
       * `context.triggerKind` can be used to distinguish between these scenarios.
       *
       * @param document The document inline completions are requested for.
       * @param position The position inline completions are requested for.
       * @param context A context object with additional information.
       * @param token A cancellation token.
       * @return An array of completion items or a thenable that resolves to an array of completion items.
       */
      provideInlineCompletionItems(document: TextDocument, position: Position, context: InlineCompletionContext, token: CancellationToken): ProviderResult<InlineCompletionList | InlineCompletionItem[]>;
   }
```

i dont know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one such solution is to use

```
    "vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger');".
```

This command triggers the function you were talking about. Putting it in a block of code that executes on user input (like a listener for key presses) could be what you are searching for.